# Is there a way to output configuration JSON files without including them in the bundle with Webpack?

Tags: webpack, octopus-deploy

I have a project which uses Webpack to bundle the client-side code and is deployed via Octopus Deploy.  I'm trying to implement a way to be able to define configuration settings which can easily be updated using Octopus when promoting builds between environments.

I would like to be able to define a JSON file (let's call it `config.json`) which can be easily transformed by Octopus and used within my application to various configuration options.  I have configured Webpack to load `config.json` which works as expected.  When I run Webpack to bundle my assets I would like to be able to output `config.json` separately to my bundle so Octopus can easily transform it.  Is this possible with Webpack and if so how would I achieve it?

If this isn't possible what other ways could I achieve the same thing through Octopus without having to rebuild the project for each environment?

Comment: Not 100% if this would work, but what about using Octopus replace variables option and simply putting the files raw in the package? Then after deployment you can pick up the transformed .json and place it in the correct directory for you, for example. http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/Substitute+Variables+in+Files

Comment: How are you configuring webpack to load config.json as a json file?  If the json-loader is used, it's no longer JSON, it's JS with the JSON inside.